# Wordpress slideshow

Tags: wordpress

Hello
I need to make a wordpress slideshow.
I need the loop to list posts as

This is the html

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="slider">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/slide01.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></li>
                                            <li>
                    <img src="images/slide02.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></li>
                                            <li>
                    <img src="images/slide03.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the php.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
    <div id="slider">
        <?php $query= 'cat=3'; ?>
        <?php query_posts($query); ?>
        <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess you have posts each containing only 1 image and you want to list these posts as a slideshow? If so, you could do it like this (untested code):

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
    <div id="slider">
        <ul>
        <?php 
            $query= 'cat=3'; 
            query_posts($query);
            if(have_posts()) :
            while(have_posts()) : the_post();
        ?>
        <li><?php the_content(); ?></li>
        <?php 
            endwhile;
            endif;
        ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```